# Can't Reboot mdraid

Tags: raid, mdadm, xfs

I just created a raid 0 array with the following commands:

```
# Install the necessary packages
sudo apt-get install xfsprogs mdadm -y

# Create the RAID 0 array.
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=stripe --raid-devices=2 /dev/sd[x] /dev/sd[x2]

# Create the XFS filesystem
sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/md0
```

However, every time I reboot (this second time without bothering to put any data on it), it always fails to mount and I have to press S to skip.

I tried with either of the following lines in /etc/fstab:

```
UUID="8aba7867-e97b-4c4c-9aa3-f61d0de4434a"    /media/storage  xfs     defaults        0       2

/dev/md0                                        /media/storage  xfs     defaults        0       0
```

Is there a step that I am missing when creating the raid array?

(Running Ubuntu 14.04 64bit desktop with 1 ssd which the OS is installed to and 2 x WD RED 3TB)

Comment: Does the system give any specific errors or warnings when it tries to mount?

Comment: not really, when I press skip and do `sudo mount -a` I get a message that the UUID does not exist, and checking `sudo blkid` confirms this. I just tried with ext4 filesystem and got the same result. Does it matter that I am running my OS on encrypted SSD?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

I just managed to get it working on another computer which leads me to believe that I was misconfiguring my `mdadm.conf` file.

This time I ran the following script after creating the RAID, but before creating the filesystem, and the RAID is available on boot:

```
echo "# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

DEVICE partitions

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays" | sudo tee /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

The content of this script was largely pulled from a [post on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/287462/how-can-i-make-mdadm-auto-assemble-raid-after-each-boot).

---

I have found a workaround that revolves around not using mdadm, hence I will not be marking this as an answer, but may be useful to others.

I created a striped logical volume which by running the following commands after creating lvm2 physical volumes on each drive through Gparted:

```
sudo vgcreate $VG_NAME /dev/sd[x]1 /dev/sd[z]1
lvcreate -i$NUM_DRIVES -I4 -l100%FREE -n$LV_NAME $VG_NAME
sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/$VG_NAME/$LV_NAME
```

I then added the new UUID to my fstab and unlike mdadm, it loads fine after a reboot. I don't know if there is any penalty in creating RAID this way, but an initial benchmark seems to show that its working with in terms of write speed.